# Convert Tensorflow Saved Model format to Keras .h5 model format

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I'm trying to use a pre-trained object detection network (TridentNet) to be able to perform object detection on the images that interest me; the model was previously saved (not by me) in the Tensorflow's SavedModel format.

The TridenNet SavedModel folder I downloaded has a format like:

```
├── assets
├── saved_model.pb
└── variables
    ├── variables.data-00000-of-00001
    └── variables.index
```

I need to convert the network from Tensorflow's SavedModel format to Keras .h5 format in order to use Keras basic functions *.summary()* and *.predict()*

I've tried various load and save combinations from both Keras and Tensorflow, but the error I get is always the same:

**AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute '_is_graph_network'**

Unfortunately I need to change format having never approached the models saved through the SavedModel format, I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of tensorflow you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Though you can use Keras basic functions `.summary()` and `.predict()` after loading the SavedModel.

Try with this below code to convert the saved model into h5 format:

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('Path of the saved model along with the model name')

# Check its architecture
new_model.summary()

#Save the model into h5 format
new_model.save('New_Model1.h5')
```

Please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#savedmodel_format)  for more details.